MySQL LEFT JOIN and OR condition with fallback
I have many tables, but the only one interesting here is the following, let's call it webpages
| companyID | lang | URL
| 1         | hu   | hu.example.com/x
| 1         | en   | en.example.com/x
| 1         | NULL | www.example.com/x
| 1         | NULL | www.example.com/x2
| 3         | NULL | www.example.com/y
| 4         | en   | en.example.com/z

My SQL is something like this
SELECT `companies`.*, `webpages`.`lang`, `webpages`.`URL`
FROM `companies` LEFT JOIN `webpages`
ON `companies`.`companyID` = `webpages`.`companyID`
AND (`webpages`.`lang` = :lang OR `webpages`.`lang` IS NULL)

For example for lang = 'hu' I got this:
| companyID | lang | URL
| 1         | hu   | hu.example.com/x
| 1         | NULL | www.example.com/x
| 1         | NULL | www.example.com/x2
| 2         | NULL | NULL
| 3         | NULL | www.example.com/y
| 4         | NULL | NULL

I'd like to achieve the following for lang = 'hu':
| companyID | lang | URL
| 1         | hu   | hu.example.com/x
| 2         | NULL | NULL
| 3         | NULL | www.example.com/y
| 4         | NULL | NULL

And for lang = 'de':
| companyID | lang | URL
| 1         | NULL | www.example.com/x2
| 2         | NULL | NULL
| 3         | NULL | www.example.com/y
| 4         | NULL | NULL

And for lang = 'en':
| companyID | lang | URL
| 1         | en   | en.example.com/x
| 2         | NULL | NULL
| 3         | NULL | www.example.com/y
| 4         | en   | en.example.com/z

So lang = NULL is a fallback for the language specific URL and a single company can have multiple fallback URLs. If there is no language specific URL given, then either a fallback URL should be chosen or if there is no fallback URL then the value should be NULL.
I am not sure if this is possible with a single SQL, currently I use PHP code to achieve the same thing, but it would be fun to have an SQL for this. Any advice how to do this?

Have you read upon the different types of JOIN yet? https://stackoverflow.com/a/28719292/1427878

Baffled by the sample data - why is aid not unique by language?

TTo be honest, I kind of understood the question before you edited, but now, I'm completely baffled by what the logic is behind the various results! 1) for lang = hu, you want lang=null, prop=z returned, but not z2. Can you please describe the logic behind deciding if z or z2 row should be returned? 2)  For lang = de you wrote it should return prop = (z or z2). Why is this logic different from lang = hu and lang = en logic?

@inf3rno where is your A table ?

@ArtBindu The content of the A table does not matter, it has the aID as primary key.

@P.Salmon I'll edit the question just a min.

@P.Salmon I edited.

@Shadow I edited again, maybe it makes more sense now.

Still not with you- I can see why an exact match would be on id and lang would work EXCEPT where there are duplicates on that basis (ie same id,lang but different prop), I can't see why you would be at all interested in other id's or why when searching for hu you would output null for 4,en or what you should publish for 3 if 3 had multiple props.

@P.Salmon I am generating a language specific XML from the data where the company info is mandatory but the URL is optional.

You want to select the line with the language code (when found), and otherwise the line with language code is null?
SELECT 
  `companies`.`companyID`, 
  MIN(CASE WHEN w1.`lang` IS NOT NULL THEN w1.`lang`
                                  ELSE w2.`lang` END) as lang,
  MIN(CASE WHEN w1.`URL` IS NOT NULL THEN w1.`URL`
                                 ELSE w2.`URL` END) as URL
FROM `companies` 
LEFT JOIN `webpages` w1 ON `companies`.`companyID` = w1.`companyID`
      AND (w1.`lang` = 'hu' )
LEFT JOIN `webpages` w2 ON `companies`.`companyID` = w2.`companyID`
      AND (w2.`lang` IS NULL )
GROUP BY companies.companyID

The MIN() is needed to make clear which value to return for a company, when multiple values are found. I choose MIN() to get the lowest (or first) value, I also could have chosen MAX() to get the highest (or last) value.
see: DBFIDDLE

I think I understand the logic except the MIN part, can you write about why it is needed?

@inf3rno:  Added a short explanation on the MIN()

Thanks, I accept your answer, it is a lot simpler than the other one.


ORDER BY CASE in subquery creates priority.
p=1 in outer query filters by unwanted languages

language-specific URL if exists
else first fallback URL
otherwise null



SET @lang = 'hu';
SELECT  c.companyID, w.lang, w.URL
FROM companies c
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT w.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY w.companyID 
            ORDER BY 
                CASE 
                    WHEN w.lang = @lang THEN 1
                    WHEN w.lang IS NULL THEN 2
                    ELSE 3
                END
        ) AS p
    FROM webpages w
    WHERE w.lang = @lang OR w.lang IS NULL
) w ON c.companyID = w.companyID AND w.p = 1
ORDER BY c.companyID;

Output:



companyID
lang
URL




1
hu
hu.example.com/x


2
null
null


3
null
www.example.com/y


4
null
null



fiddle
